# How to remove Column from objectlistview in C# winform before assigning dynamic DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I am trying to assign a new `DataSource` dynamically to a `DataListView` from `BrightIdeasSoftware`.

My data (type: `System.Data.DataTable`) which is dynamic may not have the same columns; because of this, I am encountering an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

`ErrorEncountered` : `PreviouslyRenderedMyColumn` is neither a DataColumn nor a DataRelation for table

Comment: Please post your code.  It is very difficult to know what is wrong if we can't see what you have tried.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.